# ggplot render plot with incorrect order based on value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot this following data frame, for variable `term`, based on value `val`, and facet by `gr`

I used Windows 10 64 bit, R 3.4.3 64 bit.
I have tried `fct_reorder` from package `forcats`, without success.

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data_frame(gr = c(rep('foo',3), rep('bar',3), 
     rep('cron',3)), term = c('a','b','c', 'd', 'a','e', 'f', 'g', 'h'), 
     val = c(4,5,6,1.5,1,3,1,2,4))

df %>%
group_by(gr) %>% 
arrange(desc(val)) %>%
ungroup() %>%
mutate(term = reorder(term, val)) %>%
ggplot(aes(term, val, fill = gr)) +
geom_col(position = 'identity') +
facet_wrap(~gr, scales = 'free') +
ylab('')+
coord_flip()
```

Expectation is term `a` would be in bottom of both group `foo` and `bar`.
However, in the plot, group `bar` has incorrect order, as a plotted in middle.

[image]

Comment: If you look at the docs for `reorder`, you see that the default function used is `mean`. If you change that to `FUN = min`, you get a factor ordered based on the minimum of value, and get the desired plot

Comment: Alternatively, if you're already arranging how you want, using `fct_inorder` puts the factor levels in the order they occur; `arrange` and `fct_inorder` therefore pair well together

Comment: @camille this will create another problem, if `df = data_frame(gr = c(rep('foo',3), rep('bar',3), rep('cron',3)), term = c('a','b','c', 'd', 'a','e', 'f', 'g', 'h'), val = c(4,3,6,1.5,1,3,1,2,4))`, then in foo b goes to middle instead of bottom

Answer (score 0):

@Camille 's comment was key. But you are right - it needs a different approach for another data frame - below an approach, updated as per your comment.

I used `rank` instead of `arrange` and am introducing helper columns. This is somewhat 'dangerous', because the positions of the new columns do not correspond to the old columns any more. I therefore stored this in a new data frame, in order to not change the underlying data, and also not to get confused.
I then created the factored column `term_f`, based on @ Camille 's suggestions (and after ungrouping, as you have done)

Some caveats: 
Just use `reorder(term, val, FUN = min)`, i.e. not `desc(val)`

```r
library(tidyverse)
df = data_frame(gr = c(rep('foo',3), rep('bar',3), rep('cron',3)), term = c('a','b','c', 'd', 'a','e', 'f', 'g', 'h'), val = c(4,3,6,1.5,1,3,1,2,4))

df_f <- 
  df %>% group_by(gr) %>%
  mutate(rank_val = val[rank(val)],
         rank_term = term[rank(val)]) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(term_f = fct_inorder(rank_term))

df_f
#> # A tibble: 9 x 6
#>   gr    term    val rank_val rank_term term_f
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>     <fct> 
#> 1 foo   a       4        3   b         b     
#> 2 foo   b       3        4   a         a     
#> 3 foo   c       6        6   c         c     
#> 4 bar   d       1.5      1   a         a     
#> 5 bar   a       1        1.5 d         d     
#> 6 bar   e       3        3   e         e     
#> 7 cron  f       1        1   f         f     
#> 8 cron  g       2        2   g         g     
#> 9 cron  h       4        4   h         h

  ggplot(data = df_f, aes(term_f, rank_val)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ gr, scales = 'free') +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-12-23 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This will not solve the problem completely, just this particular data `val`. Please see my comment on question post.

Comment: Thanks you  @Tjebo that works fine. Also noted on the ggplot using factor to arrange order of observation in each group, but, there is no way to fundamentally group the factorized vector. This will require creating whole new data type (multi-layered factor?), and implement ggplot2 in a way that can utilize that data type.